# How to prove generalized parallelogram Identity

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

This question was left as an exercise in my online course of functional analysis and I am able to move forward on this problem.

> Question: Show that if $x_1,...,x_n$ are any vectors in a Pre-Hilbert space $(E, ||.||)$, then $\frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{ \epsilon_1 ,..., \epsilon_n =+1 or -1} \times$$|| \sum_{i=1}^n  \epsilon_{i} x_i ||^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n ||x_i||^2 $.

Attempt: I will proceed by simplifying the LHS in hope I can prove it equal to RHS. I thought of using the C-S inequality but it doesn't seems possible in this question.

Also, $LHS \leq \frac{1}{2^n}(2 ||x_1||^2+ ... + 2||x_n||^n)$ but I am not able to show how will it be less than $\sum_{i=1}^n ||x_i||^2$.

Converse side,  proving $\sum_{i=1}^n ||x_i||^2 \leq \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{ \epsilon_1 ,..., \epsilon_n =+1 or -1} \times || \sum_{i=1}^n  \epsilon_{i} x_i ||^2 $:  I take RHS of this equation, in hope I can prove the inequality but I am not able to.

Kindly give a couple of hints on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Is a pre-Hilbert space referring to a normed space?

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way here is to attack the problem directly, much like you would do for the $n=2$ case. Here's an outline:

- First, expand the norm and use the properties of the inner product to arrive at
  $$\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{\epsilon_i=\pm 1} \sum_{i,j}\epsilon_i \epsilon_j\langle x_i,x_j\rangle$$
- Now split the inside sum to sums with $i=j$ and $i\neq j$. The first sum will give you the RHS while the second sum will cancel out to $0$. The idea here is that for exactly half of the assignments of signs the coefficient of $\langle x_i, x_j \rangle$ ($i\neq j$) will be $+1$ while for the rest it will be $-1$ which will lead to everything canceling out.